# Instagram sharing issue: Always I get the message “Unable to load image”

Tags: android, instagram

I'm working on share functionality

I 've a problem with Instagram Share

Here is my code :

- I'm trying share "account" image which is stored in "drawable" folder.This is just an example

  ```
  try {
      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      shareIntent.setType("image/*");
      shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.swathi.booklender/drawable/account");
      shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
      shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
      startActivity(shareIntent);
  }catch (Exception e)
  {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Activity available, install instagram",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

How to I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share drawable directly

First create a file from drawable then share it

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
File image = new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(image));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image via"));
```

Comment: Suppose If i get Image from Web services,In this case also I have to store image in Android device,then only I can share right?

Comment: @dya Yes. When you try to share an image using intent, You must give a uri to other application to getting your image. Because other applications not access to your res files.